# iPhone: UISegmentedControl, how to make remember the index after navigating back?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segment on my tableview controller.

segmentIndex=0 -> tableView getting loaded -> tap. navigating to another tableViewController.
segmentIndex=1 -> tableView getting loaded -> tap. navigating to another tableViewController.

Switching tableviews happens fine. The problem is that after navigating back I need to remember the previous index value. How to implement it? My current code:

```
- viewWillAppear
self.segment=[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nominals",@"Coinage",nil]];
[self.segment setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0, 200, 30)];
[self.segment setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
//self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex=0;
[self.segment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentValueChaged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[[self navigationItem] setTitleView:self.segment];


-(IBAction)segmentValueChaged:(id)sender
{
switch (self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex) 
{
    case 0:
    {
        DBAccess *access=[[DBAccess alloc]init];
        self.items=[access returnNominals:self.subCountryID nk:fromPeriod];
        [access closeDataBase];
        self.tableView.hidden=NO;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        self.segmentIndex=0;
         break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        DBAccess *access=[[DBAccess alloc]init];
        self.coinageArr=[access returnCoinage:fromPeriod period:subCountryID];
        self.tableView.hidden=NO;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        self.segmentIndex=1;
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Thank you in advance guys.

EDIT:

```
self.segment=[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nominals",@"Coinage",nil]];
[self.segment setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0, 200, 30)];
[self.segment setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
if(!self.segmentIndex)
{
    self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex=-1;
}
else 
{
    self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex=self.segmentIndex;
}

//self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex=self.segmentIndex;
[self.segment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentValueChaged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[[self navigationItem] setTitleView:self.segment];


-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
switch (self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex) 
{
    case 0:
    {
        self.segmentIndex=0;
        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        self.segmentIndex=1;
        break;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You store your value in `viewWillDisappear` and when you come back to your controller `viewWillAppear`you set back the value you stored. So what you could also do is, start by setting the value to... let's say -1. if in your `viewWillAppear`value is -1, then you set your default value, else, you use that value.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.segment=[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nominals",@"Coinage",nil]];
    [self.segment setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0, 200, 30)];
    [self.segment setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];

    if (self->_currentIndex == -1) {
        NSInteger myDefaultValue = 0;
        self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex=myDefaultValue;
    } else {
        self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex=self->_currentIndex;
    }

   [self.segment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentValueChaged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
   [[self navigationItem] setTitleView:self.segment];
}
```

You also have to store the value when the controller is about to disappear.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self->_currentIndex = self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex;
}
```

Where you defined `NSInteger _currentIndex;` in your interface

Comment: I tried to do it in the way you advised me. will publish edit in few minutes, but it didn't work.

Comment: please, see edit. It doesn't work as well. Where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can store index value in **NSUserDefaults**, and later when You navigate back, then in **viewWillAppear** you can retreive the integer value from **NSUserDefaults** and make the selected or deselected index depending upon retreived integer value.

For example:

```
-(IBAction)segmentValueChaged:(id)sender
 {
      switch (self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex)
      {
         case 0:
         { 
              // --some code--
              break;   
         }

         case 1  
         {
              //--some code--
              break;

          }  
         default:
          break;
       }
```

//Now Save selected index in NSUserDefaults like this:
 // Get the shared defaults object.

```
**NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];**
```

**// Save the index.**

```
**[settings setInteger:self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex forKey:@"MySelectedValueKey"];**

}
```

And in your viewWillAppear you can get value from the NSUserDefaults; that is which index to be selected.

```
    NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([settings objectForKey:@"MySelectedValueKey"] == 0)   
    {
      //Set up for index 0
    }

    if([settings objectForKey:@"MySelectedValueKey"] == 1)   
    {
       //Set up for index 1  
    }
```

Happy to help :)

Comment: This is also good idea, but NSUerDefaults I am using for other cases. Thank you for answer.